# Проблема с настройкой меню bootstrap'а

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста такую вещь. Я создал меню через `bootstrap`, прописал стили. Но когда я начал уменьшать размер меню, то он стал "съедать буквы". Нужно как-то поднять их. Спасибо.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.navbar-collapse {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #4c4e5a 0%, #2c2d33 100%);
  border-radius: 5px;

}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: white;

}

.navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #FF6600;
  height: 36px
}
.navbar-nav>li {
      border-right: 1px solid gray;
      height: 100%;
}
.nav {
 height:30px;
 font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Zont-SPB</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <div id="logo">
        <a href="index.html">
          <img src="logo1.png" alt="" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <div id="contacts">
        <span style="font-size: 16px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>E-mail:
        <p>
          <span style="font-size: 16px"; class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>Телефон:
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar ">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Демо-доступ</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="catalog.html">Каталог</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="contact.html">Контакты</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Высота навбара в бутстрапе влияет не только на `.navbar { height: xxx; }`, но и на свойства других компонентов, например отступов у ссылок `.navbar .nav > li > a { padding: xxx; }`.

Исходники бутстрапа написаны в LESS (SASS в четвертой версии), оба препроцессора позволяют использовать переменные для кастомизации стилей. На высоту навбара влияет переменная `$navbar-height`.

Так как вы не используете LESS/SASS-версию бутстрапа, возможности повлиять на высоту навбара у вас две:

- Перейти на http://getbootstrap.com/customize/, поменять значение `@navbar-height` и собрать себе уникальный css-файл, и подключить уже его, вместо `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css`
- Открыть исходники бутсрапа и найти все места, где фигурирует переменная `$navbar-height`, пересчитать значения свойств во всех этих местах и разместить стили у себя, они применятся поверх стандартных бутстраповских

Comment: оба совета помогли. ty

Answer (score 3):

```
.navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: white;
}
```

Добавьте сюда `padding-top: 3px;` (чтобы сохранить небольшой отступ сверху)
Также по необходимости можно добавить: `font-size: 12px;`
*(Возможно больше, возможно меньше, необходимо отталкиваться от размера шрифта в зависимости от Ваших нужд, насколько нужно уменьшить меню)*
То есть в итоге у вас должно получиться примерно так:

```
.navbar-nav>li>a {
     color: white;
     padding-top: 3px;
     font-size: 12px;
    }
```